# Python the IN and OR operators with a for loop in a list

Tags: python, list, for-loop, boolean, in-operator

I am confused on the proper way to do this in python.... So if I want to iterate through a list using a for loop and check if each element of list 'A' is in either of 2 or more other lists but I don't seem to understand how to do this... here is some basic code of what I mean:

```
>>> a
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> even
[2, 4]
>>> odd
[1, 3]
>>> for i in a:
...     if i in even or odd:
...             print(i)
... 
1
2
3
4
5
```

Why is this code printing 5 since 5 is not in the even list nor the odd list??
Also what is the proper way to do this so that I can iterate through one list and check if each element is in ATLEAST one of some other amount of lists?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is here: `i in even or odd`

This is parsed as such:

`(i in even) or (odd)`.

Python unhelpfully tries to convert the `odd` list into a boolean value (in this case `True` [because the list is not empty](http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/lib/truth.html)).

Try `i in even or i in odd`, which correctly checks if `i` is present in either `even` or `odd`.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `in` twice:

```
if i in even or i in odd:
```

`i in even` will check if `i` is in `even`. `i in odd` will check if `i` is in `odd`.

---

Otherwise, your code will be evaluated like this:

```
if (i in even) or (odd):
```

Moreover, the condition of the if-statement will always evaluate to `True` because `odd` is a non-empty list (which always evaluate to `True` in Python).

---

Finally, you need to remember that, even though its syntax is somewhat similar, Python is *not* English. :)